# NSMutableDictionary writeToFile only gives out (null)

Tags: null, plist, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

i've got the problem, that I have a NSMutableArray with some strings in it and I want to write that back to my property list. 
So I do: `[dict1 writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];`
But when I leave the view and open it again, my log on viewWillAppear just say `Plist: (null)`. Normally it should say `Plist: { whatever }. 
Anybody got an idea what's wrong with that?

Comment: First make sure that your dictionary is valid. `NSLog` it before archiving (`NSLog(@"%@", dict1)`) to see what it contains.

Comment: It contains Item 1 (Dictionary) `TemporaryDic: {
    "Item 1" = "";
}`